# Can WordPress the_content() strip the number format style?

Tags: wordpress, strip, wp-editor

I have such a scenario where I want to restrict to users to show the phone number format.

In brief I have a listing website in WordPress where users can add their own listing with description and other fields. Users add their business address in the description tab (which has wp_editor on frontend).

Now when the listing shows I want to remove the number format like phone or fax numbers have.

Is it possible that I can hide from the frontend? I tried **the_content** filter but it does not work.

Comment: Can you give the site link as well? Also do you use any plugins to implement the fields?

Comment: i used this theme https://themeforest.net/item/superlist-directory-wordpress-theme/13507181 and they have an inbuild inventor plugin which used for listing

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your theme's functions.php or any relevant page  --

```
add_filter('the_content','manipulate_content');
function manipulate_content($content){
 // Here manipulate your content, you can replace string which is exactly matching your format. eg is given below
 $content = preg_replace('/\d{3}([().-\s[\]]*)\d{3}([().-\s[\]]*)\d{4}/',
    "*phone*", $content);
 return $content;
}
```

Comment: i try this but $content return null check screen short http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2483526/f99e7f4d76728710e82950b8604387a9

Comment: after preg replace check the variable $content.. I have just given the Idea.. Please debut a bit on your own.